# Onclick not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I've been trying to get this images onclick to work but has not succeeded, I have tried looking up different ways to do it and this seems to be popular and also the setAttribute, neither works and I can't figure out why. Do you see if I make a mistake somewhere?

```
function renderMessage(theMessage){
    var text = document.createTextNode(theMessage.getText());
    var time = document.createTextNode(theMessage.getDate());
    var div = document.getElementById("writeMessages");

    div.appendChild(text);
    div.innerHTML += " ";
    div.appendChild(time);

    // Bilden

    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = 'img/deletePic.png';

    image.onclick = function(){
        alert("click");
        console.log("hej");
    };

    div.appendChild(image);
    div.innerHTML += "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Are you *calling* `renderMessage()`?

Comment: try appending the image first then bind the click event

Comment: Yes, I call it, I see the image but if I click it, nothing happens.
Appending image first then doing the onclick did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
div.innerHTML += "<br />";
```

means:

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<br />";
```

BUT whenever you do this:

```
div.innerHTML = ...
```

you are **replacing** the contents of that div with some new piece of HTML, which doesn't have the event handlers you assigned.

Try replacing that line with:

```
div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

The same goes with the other `+=` you do between text and time.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it :) How is a noob like me supposed to figure that out on my own? Thank you once again!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I suggest using jQuery and its methods `.append()` and such, because they take care of these tricky details and cross-browser issues. Not to mention it's easier to use.

Comment: Ye, probably but it's a class in JavaScript in my college and they are very specific on what tools we use and how we solve it at the moment. Probably going to learn that later on. Ok, I accepted it!